# How to grab hyperlink of a comment?

Tags: disqus

I'm fairly new to web coding in general, so explanations would be tremendously helpful to pieces of code.

Is there a way to grab a user's comment link the moment they post something and store it to a variable? By comment link, I mean the link that you can get when you hover over any comment that was posted x minutes/hours/days ago.

Comment: Comment where?  On a site that you are writing?

Comment: Yes, a site that I'm currently developing. I'm using Disqus, and the comment portion of it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/48F4a/ I'm thinking that Javascript is most likely used, but don't know much else. Care to explain further trueinViso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disqus exposes an `onNewComment` callback in the embed, so if you assign a function to this variable, it'll be called every time a user posts a comment.

Here's what it looks like:

```
function disqus_config() {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function(comment) { 
      alert(comment.id);
    }];
}
```

That comment ID can be used to construct the link to the comment as well. Something like this would work in place of `alert(comment.id);`:

`var postLink = window.location.href + '#comment-' + comment.id;`

Then do what you want with that `postLink` variable

See here for documentation: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466258